# Setting default content type in Sharepoint Framework

Tags: csom, content-type, spfx, pnp

I'm creating a list and then adding an existing content type to it. Is it possible to set the content type as default? Or would it be possible delete the primary content type?

Here's my code.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new content type, and remove the old one. Traditionally in SharePoint, the first CT is the default one, so you may want to play with that in case you need to have multiple CTs on the list.

Code here shows how to add new content type and remove the default Document CT.

```
const ctId = '0x0NEWCONTENTTYPEID';
await list.contentTypes.addAvailableContentType(ctId);

const cts = await list.contentTypes.select('StringId,Name').get();

cts.forEach(ct => {
    if (ct.Name === 'Document') {
        await list.contentTypes.getById(ct.StringId).delete();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way is just play with the order of the content type. You can do this with CSOM or PnPjs. The first content type of the order becomes the default one. Similarly if you ignore the content type from the order it will be invisible from the New button. Here is the pseduo code with pnpjs taken from one of the github ticket. (code not tested... this is just to give you a basic idea)

```
interface OrderData {
               ContentTypeOrder: { StringValue: string }[];
              UniqueContentTypeOrder?: { StringValue: string }[];
       }
const folder = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.props.listName).rootFolder;
// here you need to see if there are unique content type orders already, or just the normal one
const existingOrders = await folder.select("ContentTypeOrder", "UniqueContentTypeOrder").get<OrderData>();
const activeOrder = existingOrders.UniqueContentTypeOrder ? existingOrders.UniqueContentTypeOrder : existingOrders.ContentTypeOrder;
let newOrder = activeOrder.reverse(); //skip some if you don't want in New Button
```

change the order and update it back.

```
const folder = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.props.listName).rootFolder;
    await folder.update({
        UniqueContentTypeOrder: {
            __metadata: { type: "Collection(SP.ContentTypeId)" },
            results: newOrder
        },
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you can achieve this in SPFX as there is no method that will set default content type order for a list.